# Can't transfer to another view from a POST Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a View (ViewA) which has a button that calls an Ajax request. This Ajax request is a POST request which in turn calls a POST Action in another controller. The Action gets invoked, but on the end of this Action, I intend to go to another View (ViewB) so I return a View:

```
return View("ViewName");
```

The problem is it won't go to another View. I tried Redirect, View("Error"), and anything else but it just stays in ViewA.

Here is the Ajax code:

```
self.addToCart = function () {
    var itemId = $('#category-item').val();

    var newOrder = ko.toJS(self.Item);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/item/addorder",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: ko.utils.stringifyJson(newOrder),
        success: function (result) {
            //Empty
        }
    });
```

Here is the Action that gets called by the Ajax POST and that I want to :

```
[Route("item/addorder")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddOrder(NewOrderViewModel newOrder)
    {
        ActionResult result = null;
        string token = GetToken;

        Task<int> orderIdTask = _OrderWebService.AddOrder(token, newOrder);
        try
        {
            int orderId = await orderIdTask;
            TempData["OrderId"] = orderId;
            result = View(); // or RedirectToAction("Abc"); either way it doesn't work
        }
        catch
        {
            result = View("Error");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Could you guys explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, do a standard submit.

Answer (score -1):

As StephenMuecke pointed out, AJAX is async and won't cause the browser to change page. You can do a standard post back using a form or you could change the browsers page in the success block of your code.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/item/addorder",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: ko.utils.stringifyJson(newOrder),
        success: function (result) {
            //Naviagate to new url
            window.location = "www.stackoverflow.com";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just not use AJAX

Comment: Using ajax in this case will only degrade performance. OP is returning a view in the method so after posting the form data, the views html is then sent back across the wire (but its not even used)

Comment: @jumpingcode Yes - I was just merely offering another way that the OP could navigate to another view.

Comment: @jumpingcode Every solution is a workaround...I've merely given the OP an alternative.

Comment: @jumpingcode Personally attacking me? That's mature

Comment: @heymega I'm taking issue with the quality of your code.

Comment: @jumpingcode I'm sorry you feel that way but you're going about this all wrong. Your childish chatter doesn't belong here. Why don't you add one more closing comment and we'll be done, OK?